# Convert 16 bit hex value to FP16 in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, half-precision-float

I'm trying to write a basic FP16 based calculator in python to help me debug some hardware. Can't seem to find how to convert 16b hex values unto floating point values I can use in my code to do the math. I see lots of online references to numpy but I think the float16 constructor expects a string like float16("1.2345"). I guess what I'm looking for is something like float16("0xabcd").

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numpy.float16` is indeed a signed floating point format with a 5-bit exponent and 10-bit mantissa.

To get the result of your example:

```
import numpy as np

np.frombuffer(b'\xab\xcd', dtype=np.float16, count=1)
```

Result:

```
array([-22.67], dtype=float16)
```

Or, to show how you can encode and decode the other example `1.2345`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.2345], numpy.float16)
b = a.tobytes()
print(b)
c = np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.float16, count=1)
print(c)
```

Result:

```
b'\xf0<'
[1.234]
```

If you literally needed to turn the string you provided into an FP16:

```
import numpy as np

s = "0xabcd"
b = int("0xabcd", base=16).to_bytes(2, 'big')
print(b)
c = np.frombuffer(b, dtype=np.float16, count=1)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
b'\xab\xcd'
[-22.67]
```

Comment: But that's not what I need. I want the input to be a hex string. Not a float string.

Comment: Clearly, `b'\xab\xcd'` is a hex string? What you provided (`"0xabcd"`) is a string containing an hexadecimal integer representation, if that's what you wanted to use?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Thx!

Comment: That's alright, I added an extra example taking exactly the string you suggested, but I assumed you actually just had two bytes in a `bytes` variable, which is what the previous examples assumed (having `bytes` in `b`) - if the answer now answers your question, please use the checkmark to indicate your question has been answered. Otherwise, feel free to ask for clarification.